# Does Ionic dashboard generates Windows 10 Package ? There is only option to iOS and Android at dashboard.ionicjs.com

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, build, package, ionic3

Does Ionic dashboard generates Windows 10 Package ? There is only option to iOS and Android at dashboard.ionicjs.com.

At dashboard i can build IOS and Android Debug and Release version, but there is no option to build a Windows Mobile package.

Comment: if using ionic2 or ionic3 you should use those tags.

Comment: But its a site resource at dashboard.ionicjs.com, not the client version.

Comment: Just trying to help you match the tags people are watching.

Comment: Better now ? I need reputation. Please help voting my question. Thanks